# time series forecasting via LSTM from scratch (numpy only)

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have seen many character-language models based on LSTM/RNN implementations. Examples are as follows:

- https://blog.varunajayasiri.com/numpy_lstm.html
- https://github.com/Kulbear/deep-learning-coursera/blob/master/Sequence%20Models/Dinosaurus%20Island%20--%20Character%20level%20language%20model%20final%20-%20v3.ipynb
- https://github.com/CaptainE/RNN-LSTM-in-numpy/blob/master/RNN_LSTM_from_scratch.ipynb

how would the training and testing data be adjusted/changed so that the model can also perform time series forecasting (e.g. stock price prediction), with the record format(i.e. price indexed by time)?

For example, with specific regards to "varunajayasiri"'s implementation: how would the input vector, input size, hidden size, and the "sample", "update_status" function, and the training loop be adjusted if I want to have a dataframe of the following format as the input?

```
    index close_price
0     1        2
1     2        4
2     3        6
3     4        8
4     5       10
5     6       12
```

Below is his "sample" function

```
def sample(h_prev, C_prev, first_char_idx, sentence_length):
  x = np.zeros((X_size, 1))
  x[first_char_idx] = 1

  h = h_prev
  C = C_prev

  indexes = []

  for t in range(sentence_length):
      _, _, _, _, C, _, h, _, p = forward(x, h, C)
      idx = np.random.choice(range(X_size), p=p.ravel())
      x = np.zeros((X_size, 1))
      x[idx] = 1
      indexes.append(idx)

  return indexes
```

Comment: Reviewers, please do not flag this as duplication. My original question has been edited, and became more specific, however no one is reviewing it therefore still closed.

Comment: This question is kind of urgent. Any immediate help would be appreciated :)